# different type of animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, uibutton

I am new to `iPhone` developer,

I want to implement different `Animations` on button click, i have 5 `Button` in my home page

on each click of button, i want to navigate to a new page with different `Animation` so i want to know what are the different animation available in `iPhone`.

so far i have found only 2 animation,

(1)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"yourAnim" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:yourView cache:cacheFlag];
      ...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

(2)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"yourAnim" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:yourView cache:cacheFlag];
     ...
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

**Thanks In Advance !**

Comment: Read the documentation! They are all there!

Comment: where are they ? can you plz provide me link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link provides the UIView Animation. Go through it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes

Comment: Is there any animation which slides from Top or bottom ? like `pushviewcontroller` slides from right.

Comment: For that you'll have to use `PresentModalViewController`.

Like to push a view controller:


`[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];`

and To pop a viewcontroller:


`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: `PresentModalViewController` is working fine but when i navigated to new page, there i am unable to see my navigation bar.

Comment: Try this : May be u'll have to set 

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];`.. if your view is in navigation controller then u will surely get navigation bar.

Comment: i tried but no success, how to check my current view is `navigation controller` or not ? if not then do i need to set to `navigation controller`

Comment: if you have added the navigation controller in your app or have taken navigation based application and if your view is added in the navigation controller's view controller, then ur view is in navigation controller.you can also check as :

`NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController viewControllers]);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12683/discussion-between-iuser-and-krunal)

Answer (score 1):

These are 5 different Animation Transition:

```
UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
```

Comment: Is there any animation which slides from Top or bottom ? like `pushviewcontroller` slides from right.

Answer (score 0):

Look at CATransition class too
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Is there any animation which slides from Top or bottom ? like `pushviewcontroller` slides from right.

Comment: Yes, set type kCATransitionPush and subtype kCATransitionFromTop

Answer (score 0):

I think bellow method from you can test different type of Transition Animation....

```
- (void) pushController: (UIViewController*) controller
         withTransition: (UIViewAnimationTransition) transition
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];        
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You Can Get Idea From this May Be.....